# How to select the previous node of kendo treeview

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I am using Kendo Treeview that has select method and on select of each node I am  performing some logic.Now I want to select the node that previously selected.

My Kendo treeview as follows:

```
    $("#TreeView").kendoTreeView({
         select: onSelectTreeNodes
     });

function onSelectTreeNodes(e) {
   var kendoTreeData = $("#TreeView").data("kendoTreeView");
     if (DataChanged) {
    //Some logic
     }
     else {
        //select Previous Node
        var sel = kendoTreeData.select();
        var preNode = $(sel).prev().prevObject[0].innerText;
        var text = kendoTreeData.findByText(preNode);
        kendoTreeData.select(text);
     }
  }
```

Say OnSelect I have selected Node 'A' some logic is executed and then if I select Node 'B' and in this case 
if condition is not satisfied then it should select again node 'A'

Comment: You mean previous as the node user have select before or the previous in sequence?

Comment: Note that in the select event, TreeView.select() does not contain the node you just clicked on...it will after the event is completed, if you don't cancel it.  e.node contains the node you clicked on, though.  And to select the "previous" one, you can just do TreeView.select($(e.node).prev())...you shouldn't have to do findByText().

Comment: I tried the above..Its not selecting the previous node.